# Why am I getting this error for my LWJGL program?

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I am trying to make a window with OpenGL (Using LWJGL 2) with Java. When I tried to run, a ClassNotFoundException error came up from the Eclipse BuiltInClassLoader.

I have tried looking for the correct jar file but I couldn't open the jar files to see which packages were inside them. Here is my code:

DisplayManager.java

```
package renderEngine;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;

public class DisplayManager {

   private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
   private static final int HEIGHT = 720;
   private static final int FPS_CAP = 120;

   public static void createDisplay(){

      ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2);
      attribs.withForwardCompatible(true);
      attribs.withProfileCore(true);

      try{
          Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, 
          HEIGHT))
          Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
      }catch(LWJGLException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

   }

   public static void updateDisplay(){
      Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
      Display.update();

   }

   public static void closeDisplay(){

      Display.destroy();

   }

}
```

MainGameLoop.java

```
package engineTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import renderEngine.DisplayManager;

public class MainGameLoop {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      DisplayManager.createDisplay();

      while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){

         DisplayManager.updateDisplay();

      }

      DisplayManager.closeDisplay();

   }

}
```

I expected the output to show a window, this is the real output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/lwjgl/LWJGLException  at
> engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:11) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 1 more

Answer (score 1):

You probably put the jar files for lwjgl in the module path

i had the same error before so to fix this error, Make sure to move all 3 jar files into Classpath which is the **lwjgl_util.jar**, **lwjgl.jar**,and **slick-util**!

To do this, Right-Click the Java Project where the *MainGameLoop* and *DisplayManager* is, Then Hover your mouse into **build path**, and then click **Configure Build Path**, and go to Libraries, here you will see the 3 jar files. if the jar files are in the Module Path! move it into Classpath, Click Apply and close and then you should be good!

if the problem is still not fixed! then you probably have Java Runtime Environment(JRE) 1.7 or below! if so you can download JRE 1.8 Here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html

hope this helps! and also have a nice day.