# How do I fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException ? (Eclipse - lwjgl)

Tags: java, eclipse

**Background/Prerequisites**

I am trying to follow a game tutorial(to create flappy bird). In the
Episode - 2 it creates an empty window and I get an error.

I tried following this tutorial series to create a game using java - eclipse - lwjgl.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pUYjxeDNEs&list=PLlrATfBNZ98e5KBKGcL7ARy3DjstzI2TV&index=1&ab_channel=TheCherno
[Flappy Bird - Episode 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pUYjxeDNEs&list=PLlrATfBNZ98e5KBKGcL7ARy3DjstzI2TV&index=1&ab_channel=TheCherno)

I have installed java jdk 17.0.6 (in the tutorial it installs an older version which I thought it won't be a problem, let me know if this could be the cause), eclipse 2022 and lwjgl - 2.9.1.

I have copied the code from Episode 2 (seen below):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlMqfsOOD3U&list=PLlrATfBNZ98e5KBKGcL7ARy3DjstzI2TV&index=2&ab_channel=TheCherno
[Flappy Bird - Episode 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlMqfsOOD3U&list=PLlrATfBNZ98e5KBKGcL7ARy3DjstzI2TV&index=2&ab_channel=TheCherno)
which tries to create an empty window.

```
package    com.chris.flappy;

import     org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import     org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import     org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class Main implements Runnable{
    
    private int width = 1280;
    private int height = 720;
    private String title = "Flappy";
    
    private boolean running = false;

    private Thread thread;
    
    public void start(){
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this,"Display");
        thread.start(); 
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width,height));
            Display.setTitle(title);
            Display.create();
            
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(running) {
            if(Display.isCloseRequested()) running = false;
        }
        Display.destroy();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        new Main().start();
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

I have included in the module path the lwjgl.jar file and changed the native library location as shown in the video to the corresponding folder with the dlls, but with the difference that in the video (probably because it was an older version) it didn't have the separation of module path and class path.
[Screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqUC6.png)

I have the following workspace folders set.
[Screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgOBb.png)
[Screenshot_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZu0l.png)

**Error**

I am gettting the following error.

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.chris.flappy.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
```

[Screenshot_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg86K.png)

**What have I tried from the mentioned solutions?**

- I have tried using an older version of java (1.8) and still it doesn't work
- In this article [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644836/why-am-i-getting-this-error-for-my-lwjgl-program) they mentioned about moving jars to classpath, I tried drag and dropping them from module path as well as placing them but it seems to not work.

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Thank you.

**Comment section**

[comment_screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LakLC.png)

[comment_screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9dmi.png)

Comment: Is this native library 32-bit or 64-bit? Is the JVM running the application 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: What nitind says. Your JVM seems to be 64 bit (according to your screenshot 4: Java installed in `C:\Program Files\`, not in `C:\Program Files (x86)`). But maybe your native library is 32 bit (the video is pretty old, so this is very likely).

Comment: How do I check what that .jar is running (32 or 64 bit)?
I have downloaded them from here https://legacy.lwjgl.org/ (2.9.1 - 2.9.3)
But I think you are probably right. If thats the case what would you suggest?
Download the latest version of lwjgl? Download 32bit jvm (prob.not)? Keep in mind that for eclipse to run I need to use something around java 14 and above.

I have tried right now to make it run with lwjgl 3.3.1 but the problem Display is not used in the 3 version and I get these errors. 
@nitind Please check the edit in Comment section of the post to see the screenshots

Comment: @howlger I wanted to mention you in the above comment as well but It doesn't allow double mentioning

Comment: `*.class` files are platform (and 32/64 bit) independent. But the Java VM and native libraries are not: a 32 bit native library works only with a 32 bit Java VM (which might run on a 64 bit operating system) and a 64 bit native library works only with a 64 bit Java VM. With which Java VM you run Eclipse is a complete different thing (best use the Java shipped with Eclipse) and independent of the Java VM you use to run your code.